# Disable backorders in variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to bulk disable backorders **in woocommerce variations** for all products with sql query or filter?

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', '__return_false' );` does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  meta_value = 'no' WHERE meta_key = '_backorders';
```

With this sql-request, you can completely disable or enable all backorders in Woocommerce. Runs in phpmyadmin

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.